# Elasticsearch API python returns no values or to few (Kibana does give the correct results)

Tags: python, api, elasticsearch

Here I have a python code snippet:

```
res = es.search(index="ise-*", body=ise_query, size=10000) #First search for IP in infoblox-* index
print("Got %d hit(s):" % res['hits']['total']['value'] + " in index ise-* index.")
ise_hits = res['hits']['total']['value']
if res['hits']['total']['value'] > 0:
    for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
```

The ise_query I run: (x.x.x.x is an IP address):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "syslog_message",
            "query": "x.x.x.x"
          }
        },
        {
         "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "gte":"2022-10-06T09:00:00", 
                "lte":"2022-10-06T10:44:00"
                          }
                  }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
"size": 50
}
```

When I search in Kibana for the IP address in a timeframe I get results, when I use the python script I do not get results or to few results. What could be wrong? It's an elastic cluster btw.

Kind Regards Marc

Comment: What 3rd-party Python library do you apply to speak to Elasticsearch, in other words `es.search()` comes from which imported library?

Comment: from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

Comment: I do not see any parameter named `body`, only one which is named `query`. I am looking here: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.4.3/api.html#event-query-language-eql

Comment: Ok what do you mean by that?

Comment: Do it this way: `res = es.search(index="ise-*", query=ise_query, size=10000)`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_user_or_owner_by_ip.py", line 305, in <module>
    search_for_username()
  File "get_user_or_owner_by_ip.py", line 198, in search_for_username
    res = es.search(index="ise-*", query=ise_query, size=10000) #First search for IP in infoblox-* index
<snip>
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [query].')

Comment: I now used res = es.search(index="ise-*", query=ise_query, size=10000)

Comment: Btw I often get results but not all results like in Kibana

Comment: "I often get results but not all results like in Kibana" Maybe because of your limitation of `"size": 50`?

Comment: No It is strange but normally I should get about 5 hits. But I get only 1 or nothing or sometimes 2 or 3. If I have multiple elasticsearch servers should I query them all or will the API take care of that and use all servers in the query search.